# NUnit3 throws exception System.Runtime, Version=4.2.0.0 not found while trying to run test in NUnit3 console

Tags: visual-studio-2017, nunit-3.0, .net-core-2.0, opencover

```
Environment:
.Net Core 2.0
visual Studio Professional 2017
NUnit3
OpenCover (For code coverage)
ReportGenerator(For code coverage report)
```

Hi Nunit Team,
I am pretty familiar with MS Test framework and have worked on that extensively but was testing how suitable NUnit framework would be and so wanted to do a small POC around that. I created a small classlibrary and a unit test project. Below are the NuGet package been installed:

`NUnit 3.7.1`

But when I try to run the test cases from console runner like below I get exception saying System.Runtime, Version=4.2.0.0 assembly not found.

```
C:\Users\UN\.nuget\packages\nunit.consolerunner\3.8.0\tools>nunit3-console.exe D:\Code_Trials\BoMLibrary\BomTest\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0\BomTest.dll
```

Exception detail:

```
Errors, Failures and Warnings

Invalid : D:\Code_Trials\BoMLibrary\BomTest\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0\BomTest.dll
Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.
----> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
Run Settings
DisposeRunners: True
WorkDirectory: C:\Users\Smukherjee.nuget\packages\nunit.consolerunner\3.8.0\tools
ImageRuntimeVersion: 4.0.30319
ImageTargetFrameworkName: .NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0
ImageRequiresX86: False
ImageRequiresDefaultAppDomainAssemblyResolver: False
NumberOfTestWorkers: 4
```

Am really not sure why so? No matter what I try not able to pass through this error. Moreover, when I try to install the assembly from Nuget I don't even find a assembly with version 4.2.0.0.

Tried installing the version 4.3.0.0 of System.Runtime but no luck. Can you please help on this.

Strange thing, I have got a sample unit test project (as part of opencover nuget install) which targets .Net Framework 4.5 and have NUnit2.6.7 package installed and when I try to run that using NUnit3 console it works like charm.

Even, installing NUnit3 latest stable version 3.10.1.0 doesn't help either. Also, it's surely not an Opencover issue since opencover console just passes the test run request to NUnit console. So the issue has to be around NUnit.

Let me know if you need more information around this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer to this here https://github.com/nunit/nunit/issues/2763

`NUnit Console` doesn't run .NET Core tests - you need to use dotnet test instead. Take a look at this page:

https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/.NET-Core-and-.NET-Standard